# object TagFragments is not a member of package org.specs2.specification

Tags: scala, playframework-2.4, specs2

I have recently upgraded play version to 2.4 coming from 2.3, Since I'am  using specs2 for writing tests, I needed to add the following line to the sbt file:

```
libraryDependency += specs2 % Test

resolvers += "scalaz-bintray" at "https://dl.bintray.com/scalaz/releases"
```

But when compiling my test file I had the following errors:

```
object TagFragments is not a member of package org.specs2.specification 
 import org.specs2.specification.TagFragments.AlwaysTag
```

```
object CommandLineArguments is not a member of package org.specs2.main
 import org.specs2.main.CommandLineArguments
```

```
value eg is not a member of org.specs2.execute.DecoratedResult[org.specs2.matcher.DataTable]
 possible cause: maybe a semicolon is missing before `value eg'?
     }).eg
```

```
value urlIs is not a member of org.specs2.specification.core.SpecHeader
 "helloWorldTest".title.urlIs("index.html") ^ sequential ^  s2"""
```

Comment: What is the specs2 version in your dependencies? Can you explicitly set a version like `4.6.0`?

Comment: After checking my jars files I found version 3.6.6, I did not set the version explicitly. When I tried to set the version explicitly like this: *** libraryDependencies +=   specs2 % Test % "4.6.0" ***, I got the following error:

```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: Configurations already specified for module com.typesafe.play:play-specs2:2.4.11:test```

Comment: @Eric, I changed the  "helloWorldTest".title.urlIs("index.html") to "helloWorldTest".title.html.outdir("index.html"), but it fails

Comment: Sorry I should have directed you to https://etorreborre.github.io/specs2/guide/SPECS2-4.6.0/org.specs2.guide.HtmlOutput.html. You don't need to change the title anymore, just write `helloWorldTest.title` and you can pass the output directory as a command-line option: `sbt> testOnly *HelloWorldTest* -- html.outdir target/html`